# Parsing / Returning information from an R Object

Tags: r

First, apologies. I'm using R for a one-off project and don't know the first thing about syntax I should use to describe my problem. I've been looking at it for all of 5 minutes :(

I have an R object which has been returned and created from JSON using rsjon. It looks like this:

```
> str(theObject)
List of 8
 $ field1     : chr "somevalue"
 ...
 $ field5     : num 35.2
 $ field6     : num -80.3
 ...
 $ field8     : chr "someOthervalue"
```

I want to pull out field5 and field6, and return them as a concatenated string that looks like `35.2,-80.3`I know that this is probably trivial, but I don't know enough about R to figure out the commands to do so

What might the script I'm writing look like after I do the JSON parsing?:

```
theObject <- fromJSON(readlines(thePayload, warn=FALSE))
...
ret (concatenatedStringOfNumbers)
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use `theObject$field5` to access 35.2. You can then use the `paste` function to paste the extracted elements 35.2 and -80.3, with `sep = ","`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely. Please post as an answer so I can up your reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my comment as the answer

```
paste(myObject$field5, myObject$field6, sep = ",")
```